# JQuery Uploadify fails on second attempt only from within System.Net.WebBrowser

Tags: jquery, controls, browser, uploadify

Has anyone else run into this and know how to fix it?

We have a Windows Forms App that creates an instance of the **System.Net.WebBrowser** component, and loads a web page in it that allows the user to upload files. The web page uses the **JQuery Uploadify Plug-In** to upload files. The first time the web page is used to upload a file, it works flawlessly. However, the second time the same instance of the System.Net.WebBrowser is used for that same web page, it fails. The user can browse for the local file to upload but after selecting the file, the progress bar just doesn't move and it seems to hang there.

I've even refreshed the page within the WebBrowser and even reset the session, to no avail. It always fails until I shut down my Windows Forms application all-together. Then it works for one file again.

If the web page is accessed via IE directly (or any other browser) it works perfectly, multiple times, no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what I did is to embed Mozilla XUL Runner into my app instead of the WebBrowser control from Microsoft and it did the trick.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xulrunnerinstal/files/XULRunner%20Installer%20Binaries/0.14/XULRunner-1.9.0.4_en-US_win32_installer-0.14.exe/download